# What is this design/advert featuring cupcakes on French railway trying to say?

Tags: france, paris

I saw this on a platform at Gare de Lyon in Paris.

[image]

There was a similar design, but featuring doughnuts further down.

I’m an uncultured tourist.

What are these trying to sell / say / do? I’m particularly curious about the woman / child / shopping trolley.

Comment: That's pretty clearly an adult going into the shopping cart, not a child.  A child would have a much larger head relative to the size of its body.

Comment: Based on pictograms, I'd guess it was "treat yourself sometimes" or "add variety to your life occasionally"

Comment: Like most graphics used in advertisements, it's trying to say "I'm a really smart creative designer. Admire my work!"

Comment: "Dispose of corpses responsibly, you special cupcake you"

Comment: what if love is a greedy need :)
https://www.adopteunmec.com/lab/article/adopteunmec-lance-une-campagne-daffichage-sucree-et-coloree

Comment: Better translation: 'What if love were a necessary indulgence'

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This  is an advertisement for the  [Adopte un Mec](https://www.adopteunmec.com) dating app/website. The site is also known abroad by the different translations of its meaning "Adopt a Guy".

Their logo features the cart.

[image]

Comment: Also, the design seems to indicate that adopeunmec helps you find the 
"one and only" in a sea of boring clones.

Comment: Yep, you nailed it both.

Comment: Famous french dating website, where they always try to be creative in their advertisements.

On a personal note I always wonder what would happen if the logo was reversed, man "adopting" a woman by putting them in their cart.

Comment: @Pierpowl When the site first launched, this was the specificity of the site : it was free for women, and they were the only ones able to contact other users. This business model was meant to differentiate themselves from other websites where female profiles were swarmed by inbox mails.